# in performing double 'for loop', how to put results of 1st for loop into 2nd for loop Dataframe?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, finance

I am making a dictionary 'd'.
Then I am running for loop to get some value 'a'.

Now, when I put the value 'a' in the dictionary, all the values of dictionary are the last for looped value of 'a'. How, can I get different values of a in dictionary?

**#Problem**

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(high_correlation["Stock Name 2"])):
    a = high_correlation.loc[high_correlation["Stock Name 1"] == high_correlation.iloc[i,1]]
    for y in high_correlation["Stock Name 2"]:
        d[y] = a
```

**#Result of Problem**

```
{'AAPL':     Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
 344  ZS           CRWD         0.680416
 345  ZS           OKTA         0.604365
 346  ZS           ZS           1.000000,
 'ADBE':     Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
 344  ZS           CRWD         0.680416
 345  ZS           OKTA         0.604365
 346  ZS           ZS           1.000000,
 'ADSK':     Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
 344  ZS           CRWD         0.680416
 345  ZS           OKTA         0.604365
 346  ZS           ZS           1.000000,
 'CDNS':     Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
 344  ZS           CRWD         0.680416
 345  ZS           OKTA         0.604365
 346  ZS           ZS           1.000000,
```

**#What are the values of a**

```
Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2  corr
0  AAPL         AAPL         1.0 
  Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
1  ADBE         ADBE         1.000000
2  ADBE         ADSK         0.647194
3  ADBE         CDNS         0.622818
4  ADBE         INTU         0.653431
5  ADBE         MSFT         0.663925
6  ADBE         PYPL         0.637802
7  ADBE         SNPS         0.659900
   Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
32  ADSK         ADBE         0.647194
33  ADSK         ADSK         1.000000
34  ADSK         CDNS         0.606291
35  ADSK         SNPS         0.617291
   Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
77  CDNS         ADBE         0.622818
78  CDNS         ADI          0.607649
79  CDNS         ADSK         0.606291
80  CDNS         AMAT         0.602062
Stock Name 1 Stock Name 2      corr
344  ZS           CRWD         0.680416
345  ZS           OKTA         0.604365
346  ZS           ZS           1.000000
```

**As you can see, I am getting the last value of a in my dictionary.**

Comment: Welcome to SO. But it's unclear. See [ask]. You need to describe your problem in English. What's the key and value of your ```d```? Also post a [mre] including a sample data, ```high_correlation``` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `for`-loops or `dict`s. Here is an example using stock data from `yfinance`:

```py
import yfinance as yf

tickers = "MA,V,AMZN,JPM,BA".split(",")
data = yf.download(tickers, "2020-12-31", "2021-12-31", auto_adjust=True)["Close"]


corr = (
    data.corr() # construct correlation matrix
    .melt(ignore_index=False) # cols to rows
    .set_index("variable", append=True) # add ticker 2 to index
    .reorder_levels(["variable", None]) # reorder multi index levels
)
```

**Output:**

[image: output]